# how to split a single file into mutliple .sh files and execute one after other

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I have a file which consists of mv & cp commands over 40000 lines. I want to split it into 20 or N files as as a shell file  and run it one after another in sequence, Example if a.sh completes then I want to execute b.sh and so

Example the file has

```
hdfs dfs -mv /source/path/file.xt /destination/path/ &
hdfs dfs -mv /source/path/file.xt /destination/path/ &
hdfs dfs -mv /source/path/file.xt /destination/path/ &
.
.
hdfs dfs -mv /source/path/file.xt /destination/path/ &
```

I am using the above logic in between as a part of one script.

Comment: `split` or `csplit` command might help..

Comment: how will you split as .sh file

Comment: this is bad idea: one command can occupy multiple lines

Comment: If I execute it in a single file , I am getting GC error/ out of memory errors in threads.

Comment: What is the point of this? What problem are you trying to solve by doing it in 20 pieces?

Comment: I agree with @mark-setchell There are better ways to do this.  You could use Pig or use distcp if you could clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to split the file. Just put `wait` every after 20 lines like below which will fix your issue.:-

```
 hdfs dfs -mv /source/path/file.xt /destination/path/ &
 .
 .
 #after 20 line or more as per your requirement
 wait
 hdfs dfs -mv /source/path/file.xt /destination/path/ &
 .
 .
 wait
 hdfs dfs -mv /source/path/file.xt /destination/path/ &
 .
 .
 wait
```

To add `wait` every after 20 lines use the below command

```
 awk ' {print;} NR % 20 == 0 { print "wait"; }' yourfile.sh > newfile.sh
                      ^ change this number if you want to insert `wait` in a specific place for example if you want to put `wait` every after 30 lines make it like below

awk ' {print;} NR % 30 == 0 { print "wait"; }' yourfile.sh > newfile.sh
```

Finally:-

```
   mv  newfile.sh  yourfile.sh
```

`yourfile.sh` is the file where you have 40000 lines of commands.

****Always take a backup of original file.

Comment: Hi abhijit, I can't put wait manually after N lines because the source file has 40000 lines

Comment: @user8587005, I have modified my answer it will work for you now. Let me know if successful.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit! Is there any way to pass that no.as variable?  I want 20 or 30 to pass  as variable

Comment: Sure abhijit, So,What wait does is it will wait till the above 30 commands ran successfully and then it will start next 30 commands to run in parallel right ? PS: I am a beginner to unix

Comment: YES to both of your question. Wish you all the very best.